# RSpec - Can I add something after the 'be' for this test?

Tags: ruby, rspec

This tests works:

```
require './9_chess_game'
require './9_chessboard'

describe 'Chess Games' do
  it 'A Game' do
    expect(ChessGame.new).to be
  end
end

class ChessGame
  def initialize                                                    
    @board= ChessBoard.new
  end
end
```

but I dislike how the 'dangling' be reads.
Is there any way I can have `valid`, `be_valid`, `valid?`, `true` or something similar?  All my attempts so far have failed.

For example using `to be_valid` generates

```
undefined method `valid?' for #<ChessGame:0x00000001977650>
```

Comment: Do you hate Hamlet? You don't accept the existential use of *be*?

Comment: In the console, is `ChessGame.new.respond_to?(:valid?)` true?

Comment: Maybe the `expect(ChessGame.new).to be_truthy` is read better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RSpec by convention `object.to be_method` will call the `method?` on the `object`.

If the trailing be is making you uneasy you could try to be more explicit in what you are trying to assert.

```
expect(ChessGame.new).not_to be_nil
```

or

```
expect(ChessGame.new).to be_a(ChessGame)
```

or if you have ActiveSupport required.

```
expect(ChessGame.new).to be_present
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the equivalent `to be_truthy` as described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers

However, under what situations would you expect it `not_to be`? That is the question.